# Telerik RadWindow to replace existing window

Tags: telerik, radwindow

How can I open a telerik:RadWindow so that it replaces the existing window (parent)? I do not want the window as a modal.

Comment: You've not really provided enough information with your question to allow someone to help: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you calling a `RadWindow` from within another `RadWindow`? Are your `RadWindow` objects populated explicitly (using the content template) or are you using the `NavigateUrl` or javaScript API to load the content. More detail including Code examples would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are opening a RadWindow from within a RadWindow read this: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening-from-within-dialog.html.

If your RadWindows use their ContentTemplate it should not be needed and they should be able to move in the entire browser.

If they are already in an iframe (e.g., in a splitter pane, pageview or some other layout you have) the same approach from getting the main window (usually via window.top) will do the trick.

If you do not want an HTML popup you will need to use browser popups. a RadWindow is merely HTML + CSS + JS so it cannot be equivalent to a real browser window.

If you want certain pages to open in the main page when initially opened in a RadWindow look into these articles:
 - http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-application-alert-for-entire-page.html
 - http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-application-is-page-in-radwindow.html

or generally into frame buster scripts/tricks.